# Mythbuntu and Haupauge 2255 tuner

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv, mediaserver

Just put my box together today, using Mythbuntu and a Haupauge 2255 PCI tuner card. Server loads fine but when going through the quick setup guide and arriving at capture cards, the card does not show!

This is my first time trying to set up a media center, so my apologies, but perhaps someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with my Haupauge quad tuner pci card. Solved it by upgrading to the latest Linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you ever resolved this but I found a [possible answer](https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hauppauge_WinTV-HVR-2255) for your issue.

You might need the firmware update listed.

```
cd /lib/firmware
wget http://www.steventoth.net/linux/hvr22xx/firmwares/4019072/NXP7164-2010-03-10.1.fw
```